# stretching reciprocal graph

Tags: graph-theory, transformation

How do i show that the curve $y=\frac a{x^2}$ is a horizontal stretch of the curve $y=\frac 1{x^2}$ and how do i find the stretch factor? i have tried and added k constant in front of $x^2$, so $y=\frac a{kx^2}$ but not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle\frac{a}{x^{2}} = \frac{1}{(\frac{x}{\sqrt{a}})^{2}}$

Comment: thank you for the hint, could you explain how you got that may i ask? also would that mean $\sqrt{a}$ is the stretch factor?